# why does my image stop resizing when centered with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a DIV. I want the image to shrink if the size of the div goes below the size of the image. Bu I also want the image to be centered in the DIV.

This is my HTML:

```
   <div id="logo">
     <img src="/images/logo_2016.jpg">
   </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
#logo img {
    max-width:800px;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

This works to resize the image exactly like I want but the image is not centered in the DIV. If I try to center the image with:

```
#logo img {
    margin:auto;
    max-width:800px;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Then it is centered but no longer resizes with the div.

How can I get it to do both? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `display: block;`.

```
#logo img {
  margin:auto;
  max-width:800px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block; /* new */
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display:block;` to the image element. You can also set the `text-align:center` for the `#logo` element which is kind of a hack to it.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting #logo to a max-width also and place a text-align: center on the image, with you can style as an inline-block. See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7ewcbr95/

```css
#logo {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
}
#logo img {
    max-width:800px;
    
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```